# How to replace one parameter in an XML file with sed?

Tags: bash, shell, sed

As part of a tiny automation script that I am trying to create, I have one section which filters out the response from an API call and outputs a number such as 12345 with the following:

```
tidy -xml -i - responseformatting/response.txt > response_tidied.txt | grep externalId response_tidied.txt |  awk -F">" '{print $2}' | awk -F"<" '{print $1}' > response_tidied.txt
```

Is there a way I can pass the output obtained from this into sed, below? If I run this on its own, it works just fine. I just cannot seem to figure out how to use the value from the above tidying process into sed.

```
sed -i -e 's/\(<td>\).*\(<\/td>\)/<td>OUTPUT_FROM_ABOVE<\/td>/g' new.xml
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: You mean `tidy .. | .. | ...|  awk -F"<" '{print $1}'   | tee response_sndbxdk_tidied.txt  | sed -i -e ...`?

Comment: Thanks David. I have updated my question, as I saw I left out the file that needs to be updated with sed. I can use tee, but would I go about using the content in response_tidied.txt as the OUTPUT_FROM_ABOVE text.

Comment: That's where `tee` come in. If you have `somecmd | tee file | othercomand` then what is written to `file` and provided to `othercommand` on `stdin` are the same thing. (`tee` just splits `stdin` and sends the information both to `file` and out again on `stdout` which is piped to `stdin` for `othercommand`) I was unclear on what part of your pipeline you wanted to pick out and send to `sed`.

Comment: Thanks again, however, I am a bit lost. My apologies if I am not following along.
Is this what you mean?


 
tidy .. | .. | ...| awk -F"<" '{print $1}' | tee response_tidied.txt | sed -i -e 's/\(<td>\).*\(<\/td>\)/<td>stuff from tee<\/td>/g' new.xml

Comment: Well, no. Pipelines work left-to-right. So if you `... | tee response_tidied.txt` the file `response_tidied.txt` contains the result of the pipeline to that point and it also sends the result of the pipeline out on `stdout` to be further processed by whatever the `nextcommand` in `... | tee response_tidied.txt | nextcommand`is. (which I understand to be your `sed` command). That's why I say I'm still unclear what part of the pipeline you want to send to `sed`. Something like `a | b | c > file (and to sed) | sed ...` would be helpful to show just what you want `sed` to process.

Comment: Thanks for that. So, response_tidied.txt contains a number: 12345.
I will tee response_tidied.txt and then I expect to use that value in sed. 

The file that I am looking to update contains a lot of XML code and I want to insert that value only between <externalID> and </externalID>. This works fine when I run the above sed command as is, I would like for it to take the value from response_tidied.txt for the replacement instead.

Comment: So  `...  | awk -F"<" '{print $1}' > response_tidied.txt` results in a number `12345` (whatever) in `response_tidied.txt`. If I understand you want to use that number in  `12345` (whatever) in your `sed` expression. In that case you want to *capture* the result in a variable that you can use in `sed`. Why not let your pipeline complete and read the value from `response_tidied.txt`, e.g. `read -r var response_tidied.txt` which will read the first line in the file and store in `var` which you can then use as `sed -i -e "s/\(<td>\).*\(<\/td>\)/<td>$var<\/td>/g" new.xml`

Comment: Note, a bigger issue is `tidy -xml -i - responseformatting/response.txt > response_tidied.txt | ...` leaves the pipeline empty as all output went to `response_tidied.txt` so there is nothing left to pass on `stdout`. I think a better approach here is to re-ask (or edit) the question showing the relevant output from `tidy -xml -i - responseformatting/response.txt` and show in the output what text you need to capture to end up with `12345`. I am convinced that the entire pipeline is unnecessary and a simple pipe to `awk` could produce the number needed.

Comment: Hi David. So, I have tried a lot about eliminating the empty response part, and indeed, my example doesn't contain the part where I fixed that by using different files. I do get the number in the end when I leave out the sed part. 

So, I tried out your solution now of using a variable and I can see that the variable outputs the number if I echo it. However, if I use it in my sed statement, it just takes it as is into new.xml:

sed -i -e 's/\(<externalId>\).*\(<\/externalId\)/<externalId>$value<\/externalId>/g' emp_request2.xml

And the line in new.xml:
<externalId>$value</externalId>

Comment: You have to use `sed "..."` (double-quotes) or the variable will not expand within the `sed` expression -- look at my comment again `:)` (I ran out of characters in the comment or I would have mentioned it...)

Comment: Ah yes, totally missed that! :) 

I changed it now but I am not getting any different result unfortunately..:
sed -i -e "s/\(<externalId>\).*\(<\/externalId\)/<externalId>$value<\/externalId>/g" emp_request2.xml

Comment: I am also open for other solutions than sed if you have any ideas! :)

Comment: I don't understand the `'('` and `')'` in your regular expression. You don't need to capture `<externalid>` as you don't reinsert with a backreference later. Double check your regex is doing what you think it is. If you have the right value in your variable, it's just a matter of getting your `sed` expression right. (that may be better in another question -- which could be short and concise, just post the line you need to change, the contents of your variable and the `sed` expression you are attempting and that should be easily answerable).

Comment: It's not a 100% right, but I am still fixing it up. However, I did now get the variable to pass properly after deleting some unwanted whitespaces, so thank you very much for the help. I'll tinker around a bit more and see how it goes. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [sed - replace string with file contents](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141387/sed-replace-string-with-file-contents), use

```
sed -i "s/<td>.*<\/td>/<td>$(sed 's:/:\\/:g' response_tidied.txt)<\/td>/g" new.xml
```

Bear in mind you need to use double quotes round the sed command. The point is that you need to escape all slashes in the replacement string.